# Pasting from different space indents

Tags: vim

In vim, how do you deal with situations where you copy something that uses 4 spaces as an indent to 2 spaces?

Is there a way I can specify a number so that vim can use the correct indent size?

Answer (score 2):

If you have your `shiftwidth` and `tabstop` set to `2` already, you can paste the text, select the text you just pasted and re-indent those lines.

Something like:

```
nnoremap pi p`[v`]=
```

So using `pi` will paste your text, select it and re-indent it.

Comment: [Unimparied.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) has a similar mapping, `=p`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[p` and `]p` to put text with the indent of the current line.

See `:help ]p`.

Comment: I don't think this works when multiple lines are copied that have a different indentation. I think this will start the pasting at the correct point, but within the multiple lines selected, the indentation will still be the same one as when they were copied. Am I correct?